# in a user defined function in R, how do i check if inputs is of the right format in R?

Tags: r, arguments

If my function has input `(x,y,z)` in R, I want to write a line of code which ensures data for `x` is of the right form.

i.e. `x` is just a real number rather than anything else such as a vector or a list. I assume the code would go something like

```
if ( ... ){stop("x must be a real number")}
```

I would like to know what goes inside of the bracket instead of `...` ?

The reason is that if I write in a vector, the programme just take the first component of the vector as the input. R would give a warning about this, but I would like the programme to be stopped immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to "stop" if your argument is of length 1, and a real number

You could use `stopifnot`

```
foo <- function(x, y, z) {
  stopifnot(length(x)==1L & is.numeric(x))
 }
```

or perhaps

```
foo <- function(x, y, z){
  if(!(length(x)==1L & is.numeric(x))) { stop("x must be a real number")}
}
```

`stop` allows you to specify the error message whereas `stopifnot` will return the condition that was tested. (Both have advantages)

The benefit of `stopifnot` is that it can tell you exactly which of multiple conditions failed.for example (noting that I am now feeding multiple expressions)

```
 foo <- function(x, y, z) {
      stopifnot(length(x)==1L , is.numeric(x))
     }

foo('a')
# Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE 
foo(c(1,2))
# Error: length(x) == 1L is not TRUE
```